# Python and Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

I am new to numpy and i am trying to accomplish something that i would like help on. 
I have an array of three columns. 
C1 DateTime
C2 ItemName
C3 Value

ItemName has X predefined Unique Values

I would like to run some correlations between each ItemName based on DateTime. To make this simple i think the best way to accomplish it is to rearrange the array to look like this

C1 DateTime
C2 ItemName1Value
C3 ItemName2Value
C4 ItemName3Value

Now I would like to run some statistics and correlations between different columns based on criteria using C1 (Datetime).

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Thank you. So Numpy is not the correct package to use for this??

Comment: Pandas is built on top of NumPy and works well with the whole Python scientific stack. Pandas uses "DataFrames" (essentially a dictionary of arrays) to store table-like data and will let you easily compute stats on your data.

Comment: Thank you. helps a lot.. i will research pandas.